# String buffer fails to write data to database table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, stringio, csv-write-stream

I am porting a mongo database over to a PostgreSQL one and I came across with an issue. I am using `psycopg2`'s `COPY_FROM`, which takes as arguments a file object, the table to write to and other optional arguments. My original code looked like the following:

```
records = '\n'.join(','.join([row['id'], row['att1'], row['att3']]) for row in data)
fio = io.StringIO(records)
cursor.copy_from(fio, 'mytable', sep=',')
postgres.commit()
```

The code above works fine but fails for columns containing commas (splits by commas). Thus, I want to escape all commas and other punctuation that may interfere. For this, I used Python's `csv` module which handles this and got to the following code:

```
fio = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(fio)
writer.writerows([row['id'], row['att1'], row['att3']]) for row in data)
cursor.copy_from(fio, 'mytable', sep=',')
postgres.commit()
```

Using the code above, `mytable` remains empty no matter what. I tried iterating `fio` after writing the rows and the content is the same as in the initial code snippet (using `','.join`). I also checked the size of the object and it has about the same size in both snippets after writing the records.

What am I missing here? Why isn't the data being written to the table in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing to `fio` you are at the end of the file. You need to return to the start for when it is read by psycopg2.

Easy modification, like so:

```
fio = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(fio)
writer.writerows([row['id'], row['att1'], row['att3']]) for row in data)

fio.seek(0) # Return to beginning of file.

cursor.copy_from(fio, 'mytable', sep=',')
postgres.commit()
```

Comment: Agh! I had no idea the iterator would point to the end of the file. Thank you very much